# Lucene | How to find prefix matches at beginning of field?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, lucene.net

I want to match prefixes near the start of a field. I have this, but it's not matching the prefix; it only matches the whole word if the search term matches it. It seems like there's no way to combine SpanTermQuery and PrefixQuery.

```
        var nameTerm = new Term("name", searchTerm);

        var prefixName = new PrefixQuery(nameTerm);

        var prefixAtStart = new BooleanQuery
        {
            { prefixName, Occur.MUST },
            {  new SpanFirstQuery(new SpanTermQuery(nameTerm), 0), Occur.MUST }
        };
```

For example:

- Search term: `"Comp"`
- Want to find: `"Computer science class"` and `"Comp Sci"`
- Only finding: `"Comp Sci"`
- Don't want to find: `"Apple's latest computer"`

---

Can the [RegexpQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_10_2/core/org/apache/lucene/search/RegexpQuery.html) be made to understand positions?

Comment: could you please how the field is been tokenized or the field type applied to it.

Comment: Text, ~StandardAnalyzer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you only want to match prefixes, you can do it by having below field type for your field.

```
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

then in this case the query would be like :

```
field:comp*
```

Now you have a second for which you need NGramFilter, so you can use the below field type for your field.

```
<field name="text_prefix" type="text_prefix" indexed="true" stored="false"/>

<fieldType name="text_prefix" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.LowerCaseTokenizerFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Translating Abhijit's response, here is the Lucene.Net way to setup the EdgeNGramFilter:

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, reader);

        TokenFilter filter = new EdgeNGramTokenFilter(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, tokenizer, 3, 10);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like ngrams - but I would *not* use ngrams for this - especially not using a range of `3` to `10`. That is a lot of extra indexed data that you will potentially never use or need. Instead, you can use a new field - a `StringField` (not a `TextField`) - which will not be tokenized. You only need to index the first 10 characters of each source doc for this field. Then you can use a `PrefixQuery` against this field.

Comment: I'm currently combining different types of queries, for some of which I would want this field tokenized. Would you suggest it'd be better to keep a string version and a text version of the same text?

Comment: I think that would probably be a bad idea to use exactly "the same text" for both.